# Making a username/password syncronization scheme - D7

Tags: database, users

I need to register my users to a 3rd party service upon registration in Drupal. I have toyed around a bit with hooks, and tried to catch the password upon registration so I can insert it into another database, but to no avail. The 3rd party DB encrypts the password in a different way, so I need to get the users password in clear text, crypt it and then save it to the database.

Can anyone give me some pointers to where I should look? `hook_user_insert (&$edit, $account, $category)`, both `$edit` and `$account` contains the users encrypted drupal passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a form is submitted, its values are validated by the functions listed in `$form['#validate']` then processed by the functions in `$form['#submit']`. If there is no `$form['#validate']`, then the function `FORM_NAME_validate` will run (if any). Same for submit.

See [user_register_submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_register_submit/7). The plain text password is in `$form_state['values']['pass']`. Write a hook_form_alter and add a new submit function to `$form['#submit']`. Declare that function and put the logic you need in it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I just need some clarification. A hook_form_alter function is just to alter/add elements in a page? So why write a hook_form_alter function? A new submit ... you mean a hook_form_validate function? As I know thats the only function that operates after submission that you can alter $form_state and $form.

Comment: I hope I have clarified things in the answer.

Comment: Yes, very much so! I'm going to register now just to give you a thumbs up. Who's awsome? You are;-)