# Rehash Drupal 7 passwords into SHA1

Tags: 7, users

I need to sync my user database with another user database; the other user database uses SHA1 as hash with USERNAME:PASSWORD as algorithm.
Is there a way to rehash it that I can store it in the database?

Do you have any idea?

It should be possible to edit the user/*/edit form and hash the password on my own and save it afterwards, or am I wrong? If it can work, can you give me any tip on how?

I did a bit reasearch about editing the user_profile_form (for example: [Making a username/password syncronization scheme - D7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/making-a-username-password-syncronization-scheme-d7)) where I read that `$form_state['values']['pass']` could give me the password in plain text to hash it on my own and insert it into my database. 
Afterwards I directly tried to investigate more and tried to displa me the password with `dpm($form_state['values']['pass']);`, but I noticed (controlled with `dpm($form, '$form info for $form_id '.$form_id);`) that theres no values.

How can I get the plain text password in user_profile_form or is it impossible and only possible in user_register_form (as stated in topic above). 
In my user_registe_form is no password entered, because I use the method to get a link with E-Mail were you can login one time and change the password with user_profile_form.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

You need to look into the function [user_authenticate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_authenticate/7).

In that function, you will see there is a call to `variable_set()` that sets the path to the variable `password_inc`. So, basically you could overide the path of this file, change it so it points to your custom password.inc, in a custom module out of core code.  In that file you would redefine the same functions with your own logic.

There could well be a simpler way of doing this.  I know single-sign on can also be easily done with Drupal 7 as there are functions that make this easily available out of the box. Maybe look at OpenID code or other contrib modules if you choose to use that path.

Good-luck!

Comment: I guess this would overrides the password encryption from Drupal, am I right? Wouldn't the PhpBB3 Drupal Bridge stop working after this change?
I definitly need the password in the above described algorithm, so I can't choose Open ID (also I think PhpBB3 Drupal Bridge wouldn't work with Open ID either).
Everything is kinda complicated, though.

Comment: The true pain in the ass is, not to hack the Drupal Core, it would be so easy with some hacks. ;)

Comment: password.inc is Drupal's way to have a pluggable password mechanism so that you can implement your own without hacking core. That file contains a list of functions to hash a password and later on verify it, you just need to make sure that the functions that drupal expects are in there then you can do whatever you want within.

Comment: @Leandros this depends on how phpBB / Drupal bridge is coded. If a user signed on to Drupal is automatically logged in to phpBB, there are chances it would work but I can't say without looking at the code.

Comment: I solved it. A big thanks so stefgosselin, this worked, I put my hash algorithm in user_hash_password, hash it with my algorithm and put it into db and use the stock Drupal way to hash it for Drupal and insert it intp Drupal db. 
The only trick I used, is that I assigned $password to another variable, because it seemed $password can only be used once. This doesnt effect the Bridge, she is working fine.